# Dual y-axis matching on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm representing blood pressure on a graphic and I want to represent both systolic and diastolic and the graphic. Usually, these graphics are shown together following these rules:

90 Systolic pressure should be at same level as 60 diastolic
140 Systolic pressure should be at same level as 90 diastolic

So I thought it was because of max and mins that are set person basis so I developed this to try to solve that issue:

```
function getObjectSystolicDiastolic(){
    var min_systolic = getMinValue(80,person.data,10),
        max_systolic = getMaxValue(150,person.data,10),
        min_diastolic = getMinValue(50,person.data,10),
        max_diastolic = getMaxValue(120,person.data,10),
        min_systolic_eq = min_diastolic*(140-90)/(90-60) + 90 - 60*(140-90)/(90-60),
        max_systolic_eq = max_diastolic*(140-90)/(90-60) + 90 - 60*(140-90)/(90-60);

    // Getting the largest range
    var min_total = min_systolic < min_systolic_eq ?  min_systolic : min_systolic_eq;
    var max_total = max_systolic < max_systolic_eq ? max_systolic : max_systolic_eq;

    return {
        min_systolic : min_total,
        max_systolic : max_total,
        min_diastolic : (min_total - 90 + 60*(140-90)/(90-60))*(90-60)/(140-90),
        max_diastolic : (max_total - 90 + 60*(140-90)/(90-60))*(90-60)/(140-90)
    };
}
```

That, basically gets min and max values first from person data or the value supplied. For example `getMinValue(80,person.data,10)` would return a value not greater than 80 even if all values are greater than that.

[image: Graphic]

But it doesn't work. It matches the first set but then it fails.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: A jsFiddle would really help speed up...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A very nice question !!!

It is more of a math/geometry issue than a programming/highchart issue. But hey there is an entire subject on this jugglery. ***Computer Graphics !!***

If I got your question right (I hope I did, else spent an hour solving a non-existent problem, and another drafting an understandable answer).

- You always want valueX1(90) to align with valudY1(60) and valueX2(140) to align with valueY2(90). X and Y are plotted on different y-axis.

Here is the solution.
All we need to do is align the min's and max's of the two axes correctly for the required points to also align correctly by themselves.

Here is how we do that.

- Accept the min & max that is calculated by highcharts as it is for one of the axes and calculate the min & max of the other axis based on the following. (Which axis to accept can be tricky, will leave that to be out of scope for this question or as home work =] ). Lets go ahead with accepting the 1st axis' values from highchart and calculate values for second ourselves.
- How to calculate min2/max2 based on min1/max1?

  We use something known as **[Two-point form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form)** of solving linear equations

  ```
  y - y1 = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)*(x-x1)
  ```

  here x1=90,y1=60,x2=140,y2=90. Put a value of x to get corresponding value of y. Put min1 to get min2, put max1 to get max2.

**Code**

```
var ticksX = {
    t1: 90,
    t2: 140
};
var ticksY = {
    t1: 60,
    t2: 90
};

function findY(X) {
    return ticksY.t1 + (X - ticksX.t1) * (ticksY.t2 - ticksY.t1) / (ticksX.t2 - ticksX.t1);
}
```

Adjust min/max of series2 based on calculated (by highcharts) min/max of series1 on chart load

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({...}, function() {
  var minX = this.yAxis[0].getExtremes().min;
  var maxX = this.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max;
  this.yAxis[1].setExtremes(findY(minX), findY(maxX));
});​
```

**[Aligning ticks in multiple axes | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/3qdkc/)**

You will need to fiddle around with the ticks settings and gridlines. Will leave that out of scope here as they make up more for a different question

**Update: Code to readjust the ticks based on new extremes**

```
//Adjusting ticks
var ticks = 5;
var intervalX = (maxX - minX) / (ticks - 1);
var intervalY = (maxY - minY) / (ticks - 1);
var xTicks = [],
    yTicks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ticks; i++) {
    xTicks.push(minX + i * intervalX);
    yTicks.push(minY + i * intervalY);
}

chart.yAxis[0].options.tickPositions = xTicks;
chart.yAxis[1].options.tickPositions = yTicks;

chart.yAxis[0].redraw(false);
chart.yAxis[1].redraw(false);
chart.redraw();
```

Comment: First, thanks for your time Jugal, you really opened my mind. Here is your requested jsFiddle with the code you provided and, as you can see, it's not working... :(

http://jsfiddle.net/gsf8F/

Comment: Hey @AntonioLaguna I have updated my answer to be better explanatory (at least that was the plan). Check that out, while I play with your fiddle

Comment: @AntonioLaguna http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/gsf8F/1/ Like I have mentioned in the answer, you will need to play around to get the ticks and gridlines correctly in place. Give it a try not that difficult.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/3qdkc/ & http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/gsf8F/6/ with ticks aligned, also updated the answer. Gotta catch some sleep now !!!

Comment: I tried but the ticks shown aren't rounded like 90, 100, 110 but floated like 92.5.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna did you see this fiddle? jsfiddle.net/jugal/gsf8F/6 Anyway, the bounty closes today